# ASP MVC 5 Empty Nested List of Model List on submit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list

I have an issue creating form which contains dynamic list with dynamic sub-list. after submit - nested list of the list item is empty.
How it works
I have a View which contains HtmlHelper extension wrapper

```
@Html.CollectionEditorFor(m => m.Problems, "Edit/_ProblemEditor", "/Opportunity/GetProblemEditor")
```

If simplify extension it looks like this

```
public static IHtmlString CollectionEditorFor<TModel, TItem>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
        Func<TModel, IEnumerable<TItem>> collection,
        string partialViewName,
        string controllerActionPath)
    {
        var editorId = "CollectionEditor_" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
        var output = new StringBuilder();

        output.AppendLine(@"<ul id=""" + editorId + @""">");
        var items = collection(html.ViewData.Model);
        if (items != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in collection(html.ViewData.Model))
            {
                output.AppendLine(
                    viewDataDictionary != null
                        ? html.Partial(partialViewName, item, viewDataDictionary).ToString()
                        : html.Partial(partialViewName, item).ToString());
            }
        }

        output.AppendLine(@"</ul>");
        /// Here some JS code to do adding and deleting
        return new HtmlString(output.ToString());
    }
```

Everything is simple here. I pass the model field, name of partial view to load and action which is used to load new partial view on adding element.

_ProblemEditor partial view looks like this:

```
@using BoxxStep.Web.Infrastructure.Extentions
@model BoxxStep.Web.Models.Opportunity.Details.ProblemViewModel    
<li>
    @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Problems"))
    {
        <div class="double">
            <button value="Add" type="button" collection-button="buttonAddProblem" class="btn-icon add">
                <i class="icon-plus"></i>
            </button>
            <button value="Delete" onclick="$(this).parent().parent().remove();" collection-button="deleteProblem"  style="display: none;" class="btn-icon delete" type="button">
                <i class="icon-minus"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="w-input">
            <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-8 col-xs-6">
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ProblemText, new { placeholder = Model.GetDisplayName(m => m.ProblemText) })
                <i class="icon-criteria" title="@Model.GetDisplayName(m => m.ProblemText)"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="text-box">
                @Html.CollectionEditorFor(m => m.Symptoms, "Edit/_ProblemSymptomEditor", "/Opportunity/GetProblemSymptomEditor")
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</li>
```

Here I want to show nested list of Symptoms using the same wrapper and _ProblemSymptomEditor partial view which looks very similar:

```
@using BoxxStep.Web.Infrastructure.Extentions
@model BoxxStep.Web.Models.Opportunity.Details.ProblemSymptomViewModel

<li>
    @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Problems.Symptoms"))
    {
        <div class="single">
            <button value="Add" collection-button="buttonAddSymptom" type="button" class="btn-icon add">
                <i class="icon-plus"></i>
            </button>
            <button value="Delete" onclick="$(this).parent().parent().remove();" collection-button="deleteSymptom" style="display: none;" class="btn-icon delete" type="button">
                <i class="icon-minus"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="w-input">
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SymptomText, new { placeholder = Model.GetDisplayName(m => m.SymptomText) })
            <i class="icon-motive" title="@Model.GetDisplayName(m => m.SymptomText)"></i>
        </div>
    }
</li>
```

Actions which I use to add new items very simple and looks like this:
To load for parent list:

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult GetProblemEditor()
        {
            return this.PartialView(
                "Edit/_ProblemEditor",
                new ProblemViewModel
                    {
                        Symptoms = new List<ProblemSymptomViewModel> { new ProblemSymptomViewModel() }
                    });
        }
```

And to load nested list item:

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult GetProblemSymptomEditor()
        {
            return this.PartialView("Edit/_ProblemSymptomEditor", new ProblemSymptomViewModel());
        }
```

Parent simplified View Model which contains list of Problems

```
public class OpportunityEditViewModel
{
    public OpportunityEditViewModel()
    {
        this.Problems = new List<ProblemViewModel>();
    }

    [DisplayName("Company Name")]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Problems")]
    public List<ProblemViewModel> Problems { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Town / City")]
    public string TownCity { get; set; }
}
```

ProblemViewModel view model is here. It contains list of Symptoms:

```
public class ProblemViewModel
{
    public ProblemViewModel()
    {
        this.Symptoms = new List<ProblemSymptomViewModel>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Problem")]
    public string ProblemText { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Symptoms")]
    public List<ProblemSymptomViewModel> Symptoms { get; set; }
}
```

And finally view model of Symptom is fairly simple:

```
public class ProblemSymptomViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Symptoms")]
        public string SymptomText { get; set; }
    }
```

Form is submitted to next action:

```
    [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<JsonResult> SaveCompany(OpportunityEditViewModel model)
        {
            if (!this.ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                this.AddValidateMessages();
                return this.Json(new { success = false }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
/// Some Business logic here

            return
                this.Json(
                    new
                        {
                            success = result.Succeeded,
                            companyId = result.Entity.CompanyID,
                            opportunityId = result.Entity.Id
                        },
                    JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

And on submit - everything is cool with Problems. List of problems reflects correct amount of items on form, correct data, everything is ok but nested list of Symptoms is completely empty. And it doesn't meter if I add it dynamically or I prepare list of elements on load. 
Rendered HTML looks like this:
[image: Rendered HTML looks like this]
Can somebody help me to solve the issue? I've spent week trying to solve the issue and without result. It looks like only me want to have list inside list :) With one level list everything is ok and works. But if have 2 levels lists - it doesn't work at all. Strange.

Thank you a lot for any help

Comment: The `BeginCollectionItem()` helper does not work with nested collections. Your inputs would need to look like `name="Problems[xxxx].Symptons[xxxx].SymptonText"` where `xxxx` is is a `Guid`

Comment: Thank you. I suspected that nested collection should know about parent one.

Comment: You can have a look at [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wqE6Rb) to see how you can make it work (its a full client side solution for dynamically adding/removing items). There is also [this helper method](http://www.joe-stevens.com/2011/06/06/editing-and-binding-nested-lists-with-asp-net-mvc-2/) although I have not tried that out